# Front matter generates invalid CSS

Tags: jekyll

**Update**: After a conversation with a project maintainer and a few changes on my part, imports are working again (see below), but my path to the stylesheet in the head is incorrect. If I have my main file as `screen.css` or similar, what is the recommended way to reference this in my `<head>` element?

My `_config.yml` for assets:

```
assets:
  compress:
    css: false
    js: false

    autowrite: true
    cache: .asset-cache
    cache_type: filesystem
    skip_baseurl_with_cdn: false
    skip_prefix_with_cdn: false
    prefix: "/assets"
    digest: true

  sources:
  - assets/css

  features:
    liquid: false
    integrity: false
    automatic_img_size: true
    automatic_img_alt : true
```

`

Here's my `screen`stylesheet:

```
@import "variables";
@import "grid";

body {
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-size: 18px;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.social ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.social ul li {
  display: inline;
}

.social ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.rights {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Any repository url can help.

Comment: @DavidJacquel At this point, it's only a local branch, I will update with the SCSS file I have.

Comment: Error seems to be in `variables` import.